# Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase'

Tags: json, angular, indexeddb, dexie

I am trying to store a JSON object (100MB size) in google chrome indexedDB and getting this error:

```
error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': The keyPath option is not a valid key path.
```

code:

```
    var db = new Dexie ("TheList",);
    db.version(1).stores({
      list1: "++id,name",
      list2: this.Items.toString()
      });
       
    db.open().then(result => {
    // Success
    }).catch(e => {
    console.log("error: " + e);
    });
```

What didn't work:

Setting 'KeyPath' with:

```
db.createObjectStore("instruments", { keyPath: "My_Watchlist"});
```

This code throws error `Property 'createObjectStore' does not exist on type 'Dexie'.ts`

How to fix?

Comment: I suggest you read the document before trying to code, here in the document says: `Automatically upgrades your schema between versions - no need to createIndex() or createObjectStore().` https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie.js.html#compared-to-other-indexeddb-wrappers-what-does-dexiejs-do-different

Comment: Alright so what is the meaning of this error? ‘error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': The keyPath option is not a valid key path.’

Comment: Anything I can do? Just trying to save an object in indexedDB…